# FizzBuzz in Scratch

Tags: fizzbuzz, scratch

## Before you close vote:

[Yes, Scratch questions are okay](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/are-scratch-questions-okay-on-code-review).

[Link to project on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/89980448/)

> For the hundredth [fizzbuzz](/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) question, I'd thought I'd spruce it up a bit and post something new.

So, first make three variables named `i`, `iterations` and `string`:

[image: variables]

And a list named `ListOfFBs` (FBs = FizzBuzzes)

[image: list]

Here is my main code:

### [image: main code]

Which produces an output like:

[image: output]

Comment: OMG 100 [tag:fizzbuzz] questions! Who will be the first to get the tag badge?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting `iterations` programmatically to 30, I recommend making it a slider so that it can serve as your input.

To clear `ListOfFBs`, you can just do `delete all of LisfOfFBs` instead of

> ```
> set i to 1
> repeat (length of ListOfFBs):
>     delete i of ListOfFBs
> ```

I think we can do away with `i` and `string`.  `i` is just `length of ListOfFBs`.  `string` is just `item last of ListOfFBs`.

### Suggested solution

[image: Variable: Iterations and List: ListOfFBs]

[image: Program]