# You have no respect for logic

Tags: fizzbuzz, arnoldc

Inspired by [Hosch250](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=24250418#24250418), [TopinFrassi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=25888128#25888128), [Legato](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=24250341#24250341) and the recent milestone of having [our 100th](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/112708/52915) [fizzbuzz](/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) question on Code Review I decided to add an [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC) FizzBuzz to the collection.

I haven't found any best practices about the language, but I assume the code needs to be VERBOSE. For those unfamiliar with the language, a small excerpt of the keywords:

> ```
> True              NO PROBLEMO
> ModuloOperator    I LET HIM GO
> DeclareInt        HEY CHRISTMAS TREE
> AssignVariable    GET TO THE CHOPPER
> ```

The challenge itself doesn't need introduction. Write all numbers from 1 up till and including 100, but:

- Write `Fizz` instead of the number when divisible by 3
- Write `Buzz` instead of the number when divisible by 5
- Write `FizzBuzz` instead of the number when divisible by 15

```
LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY modulo
  I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE dividend
  I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE divisor
  GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE quotient
      YOU SET US UP 0
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE remainder
      YOU SET US UP 0
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE product
      YOU SET US UP 0
    GET TO THE CHOPPER quotient
      HERE IS MY INVITATION dividend
      HE HAD TO SPLIT divisor
    ENOUGH TALK
    GET TO THE CHOPPER product
      HERE IS MY INVITATION divisor
      YOU'RE FIRED quotient
    ENOUGH TALK
    GET TO THE CHOPPER remainder
      HERE IS MY INVITATION dividend
    GET DOWN product
  ENOUGH TALK
  I'LL BE BACK remainder
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY

LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY divisible
  I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE dividend
  I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE divisor
  GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE result
    YOU SET US UP 0
    GET YOUR ASS TO MARS result
    DO IT NOW modulo dividend divisor

    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE isZero
    YOU SET US UP 0
    GET TO THE CHOPPER isZero
    HERE IS MY INVITATION result
    YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME 0
  ENOUGH TALK

  I'LL BE BACK isZero
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY

IT'S SHOWTIME
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE maxValue
    YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE n
    YOU SET US UP 0
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE divisible
    YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE multiple
    YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO

    STICK AROUND maxValue
        GET TO THE CHOPPER n
        HERE IS MY INVITATION n
            GET UP 1
        ENOUGH TALK
        GET TO THE CHOPPER maxValue
            HERE IS MY INVITATION 100
            LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET n
        ENOUGH TALK

        GET YOUR ASS TO MARS multiple
        DO IT NOW divisible n 15
            BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE multiple
            TALK TO THE HAND "FizzBuzz"
            BULLSHIT
            GET YOUR ASS TO MARS multiple
            DO IT NOW divisible n 5
                BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE multiple
                TALK TO THE HAND "Buzz"
                BULLSHIT
                GET YOUR ASS TO MARS multiple
                DO IT NOW divisible n 3
                    BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE multiple
                    TALK TO THE HAND "Fizz"   
                BULLSHIT
                    TALK TO THE HAND n
                YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
            YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
        YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
    CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Comment: `HEY CHRISTMAS TREE, YOU SET US UP`. God I love that language

Comment: Instead of "fizz" and "buzz" you should use "Arnold" and "Schwarzenegger"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's incorrect/inconsistent indentation in:

> ```
> HEY CHRISTMAS TREE result
> YOU SET US UP 0
> ```

and

> ```
> HEY CHRISTMAS TREE isZero
> YOU SET US UP 0
> ```

---

The [ArnoldC wiki](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC/wiki/ArnoldC) says you should declare 0s and 1s as the "macros" `@I LIED` and `@NO PROBLEMO`

```
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE isZero
    YOU SET US UP @I LIED
```

---

In your method `divisible`, the end of method statement is not on the same indentation as the start declaration.

---

The indentation in these two blocks is two vs four:

> ```
> IT'S SHOWTIME
>     HEY CHRISTMAS TREE maxValue
> ```

and:

> ```
> LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY divisible
>   I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE dividend
> ```

You ought to stick to one consistently.

---

> ```
> IT'S SHOWTIME
>     HEY CHRISTMAS TREE maxValue
>     YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
> ```

There we go! Using the macros!

Oh, wait...

> ```
> HEY CHRISTMAS TREE n
> YOU SET US UP 0
> ```

Never mind...

---

And again...

> ```
>     HERE IS MY INVITATION n
>         GET UP 1
> ```

Comment: I'm fairly certain it can print both Fizz and Buzz when encountering multiples of 3 and 5, but I'll get back to you about that when I'm back at home.